# How to keep a file's format if you use the uniq command (in shell)?

Tags: unix, file, shell, sorting, duplicates

In order to use the uniq command, you have to sort your file first.

But in the file I have, the order of the information is important, thus how can I keep the original format of the file but still get rid of duplicate content?

Comment: Do you want to keep only the first occurrence of the pattern? Or only the last? You have to be a bit more specific than this...

Comment: Well the file is something like this.

pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
pattern4

pattern1
pattern2
etc...

pattern1 differs from pattern2, and so forth. E.g.) pattern1 is a title, and pattern2 is a phone number.

If I sort the file, phone numbers won't be under the right title, etc.

Comment: I forgot this comment section doesn't keep the format. So that post above might be a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Plenty of answers. I'll check them out after I come back from lunch and choose a best answer.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another awk version:

```
awk '!_[$0]++' infile
```

Comment: Print only when seen for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

This `awk` keeps the first occurrence. Same algorithm as other answers use:

```
awk '!($0 in lines) { print $0; lines[$0]; }'
```

Here's one that only needs to store duplicated lines (as opposed to all lines) using `awk`:

```
sort file | uniq -d | awk '
   FNR == NR { dups[$0] }
   FNR != NR && (!($0 in dups) || !lines[$0]++)
' - file
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also the "line-number, double-sort" method.

```
 nl -n ln | sort -u -k 2| sort -k 1n | cut -f 2-
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that works with very large files. But shouldn't that be "sort -k 1n" (numeric sort)?

Answer (score 1):

You can run uniq -d on the sorted version of the file to find the duplicate lines, then run some script that says:

```
if this_line is in duplicate_lines {
    if not i_have_seen[this_line] {
        output this_line
        i_have_seen[this_line] = true
    }
} else {
    output this_line
}
```

Comment: The benefit of doing this as opposed to slightly simpler solutions, btw, is that you're not keeping a mapping of every line in the file, only the duplicate lines.

Comment: oh wait. didn't thought about -d . silly litb. well teh comm can be cut out then in favor of it :)

Comment: final edition after put in -d instead of using comm: sort file.txt | uniq -d | awk 'FNR==NR { dups[$0]; } FNR!=NR { if($0 in dups) { if(!($0 in lines)) { print $0; lines[$0]; } } else print $0; }' - file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Using only uniq and grep:

**Create d.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
sort $1 | uniq > $1_uniq
for line in $(cat $1); do
cat $1_uniq | grep -m1 $line >> $1_out
cat $1_uniq | grep -v $line > $1_uniq2
mv $1_uniq2 $1_uniq
done;
rm $1_uniq
```

**Example:**

```
./d.sh infile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some horrible O(n^2) thing, like this (Pseudo-code):

```
file2 = EMPTY_FILE
for each line in file1:
  if not line in file2:
    file2.append(line)
```

This is potentially rather slow, especially if implemented at the Bash level. But if your files are reasonably short, it will probably work just fine, and would be quick to implement (`not line in file2` is then just `grep -v`, and so on).

Otherwise you could of course code up a dedicated program, using some more advanced data structure in memory to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks unwind. The file I have right now is just a sample file so it's rather short. But the files I will be using it on are going to be large. I'll see what others suggest, and I'll probably try out your suggestion for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in $(sort file1 | uniq ); do
    grep -n -m1 line file >>out
done;

sort -n out
```

first do the sort,

for each uniqe value grep for the first match (-m1)

and preserve the line numbers

sort the output numerically (-n) by line number.

you could then remove the line #'s with sed or awk